# Exchange Server Online Rewriting "To" Addresses

Tags: exchange

I'm using Exchange Server as part of a 365 subscription.

I've added multiple 'accepted domains'.

There is a single mailbox, with multiple email addresses using a mix of these accepted domains. I can receive email sent to any of these addresses without a problem.

But for some reason no matter which of these email addresses I send to, once the message arrives the "To:" addresses has been rewritten. This happens if I downloaded the messages in Outlook or another mail program so I assume it's happening in Exchange Server.

The "To:" address is the User ID of the mailbox.

I've know there's a feature on On Premise Exchange (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/edge-transport-servers/address-rewriting-procedures?view=exchserver-2019) but for the life of me I can't figure out how to turn it off.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, whichever of the specific mailbox's email addresses is put to the 'To:', once the messages are received, the 'To:' address will be rewrote? Is my understanding right? What does the address to rewritten to?

As far as I know, the address rewrite is not supported in Office 365 by default. Do you have Edge Transport server configured in your environment?

To disable address rewriting, run the following command:
`Disable-TransportAgent "Address Rewriting Inbound Agent"; Disable-TransportAgent "Address Rewriting Outbound Agent"`

Comment: Hi, what's going on with your problem now?